# Unpack nested list into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a dictionary as below. What I want to do is:

```
NestedList = [["key1","key2"],["val1a","val2a"],["val1b","val2b"]]

mydict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in NestedList}
print mydict

Runtime error (ValueErrorException): need more than 2 values to unpack
```

This doesnt work as it wants to unpack the first list into a,b,c rather than unpack the first index of each list into a,b,c. What does work is this:

```
mydict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in zip(NestedList[0],NestedList[1],NestedList[2])}
print mydict

{'key1': {'val1a': 'val1b'}, 'key2': {'val2a': 'val2b'}}
```

However, I don't want to have to unpack the nested list as above. How do I rewrite this to avoid the unpacking and zipping?

N.B I can avoid this in this instance by redefining my NestedList, however the point in general still stands - how would I do this when I can't just rewrite my input list?

Comment: Why not just index into the nested list directly and read the values out? Is `NestedList` supposed to be an arbitrary long list that repeats every 3 tuples?

Comment: There can be any number of keys and multiple values per key. I guess my question is really one about transposing the matrix, which I found out I can do by the zip(*NestedList) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is about:

```
NestedList = [["key1","key2"],["val1a","val2a"],["val1b","val2b"]]
mydict = {a:{b:c} for a,b,c in zip(*NestedList)}
print(mydict)
```

Comment: Bingo. I actually figured this out myself about an hr after posting this question, but thought it would be useful if anyone else comes across this issue as I couldn't find any similar questions anywhere.